# How to set the navigation bar to the top in Table View?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uinavigationbar

How can i set the navigation bar to the top in a Table View within storyboard interface builder? Is it possible?

If i add a navigation bar to my Table View i get it under my records only!

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2

Comment: set frame of tableview.frame.origin.y = 44

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not add the navigation bar yourself. Interface builder will do that automatically when a scene is embedded into a navigation controller or part of the navigation stack. So  if your tableview is the root controller choose your scene and then go to:

> Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller

Otherwise the navigation bar will be added automatically when you connect a segue from another controller (that is part of the stack) to your tableview controller.

Comment: Works perfectly after embedding the scene in a Navigation controller