# How do I make a navigation bar at the top of my TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

sorry if the title is somewhat misleading.

I have an app with a main view and behind that a slide out menu with a tableView, like the Facebook app.

What I want to accomplish is to have something like a tool bar or a imageView or anything that can either display an image or have a imageview and lable on top of it.

But I want it to be on the top of all the tableViewCells and when you scroll up the cells disappears beneath the "toolbar".

Sorry if the question is a bit unclear but feel free to edit.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the navigation bar to the top in Table View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078844/how-to-set-the-navigation-bar-to-the-top-in-table-view)

Comment: can you put a screen shot of slide out menu and which library are you using to get slide out menu ??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that,you should not add the navigation bar yourself.

Interface builder will do that automatically when a scene is embedded into a navigation controller or part of the navigation stack.

So if your tableview is the root controller choose your scene and then go to:

```
Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller
```

Otherwise the navigation bar will be added automatically when you connect a segue from another controller (that is part of the stack) to your tableview controller.

Hope it helps you.